# Constrained quadratic optimization with the quadProg library

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, quadprog, quadratic-programming

I have a vector `A` of length `N`. Also I have `N*N` matrix `C`. I want to maximize following equation :

```
minimize (- (w_transpose * A) + p * w_transpose * C * w)
```

Where `w` is a vector of length `N`, with constraints that each `w` is non-negative and sum of all `w` is 1.

I have seen a package called `quadProg`. There I need to specify :

`Dmat = C`, `dvec = A`, and `bvec = w`

but not sure how to apply above mentioned constraints there.

I suppose I could provide `Amat` to be an identity matrix, which will keep all `w` non-negative. But not sure how to keep `w` normalized (sum equal to zero). Actually I could normalize them later as well, but still wondering if I can do it here itself.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I am stuck at the start itself as I am unable to figure out what those parameters exactly mean and how can I relate mine with those mentioned at:  `http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quadprog/quadprog.pdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `solve.QP` function from quadprog. From `?solve.QP`, we read that `solve.QP` solves systems of the form `min_b {-d'b + 0.5 b'Db | A'b >= b0}`. You are solving a problem of the form `min_w {-A'w + pw'Cw | w >= 0, 1'w = 1}`. Thus, mapping between the forms:

- `d = A` (this is called `dvec` in the arguments to `solve.QP`)
- `D = 2pC` (this is called `Dmat` in the arguments to `solve.QP`)
- For the first set of constraints, you have `I'w >= 0`. The final constraint can be reformulated as `1'w >= 1` and `-1'w >= -1`. Therefore your A matrix of constraints (`Amat` in the arguments to `solve.QP`) is the identity matrix with a 1 vector and a -1 vector appended on the right, and the right-hand side b0 (`bvec` in the arguments to `solve.QP`) is the 0 vector with a 1 and -1 appended.

You can put it all together in R pretty easily:

```
library(quadprog)
solve.my.QP <- function(A, p, C) {
  solve.QP(Dmat=2*p*C,
           dvec=A,
           Amat=cbind(diag(1, length(A)), rep(1, length(A)), rep(-1, length(A))),
           bvec=c(rep(0, length(A)), 1, -1))$solution
}
```

You can test it on some simple 2-dimensional problems:

```
# Even penalty
solve.my.QP(c(0, 0), 1, diag(1, 2))
# [1] 0.5 0.5

# Encourage inclusion of first variable
solve.my.QP(c(0.1, 0), 1, diag(1, 2))
# [1] 0.525 0.475
```